# ExtJS, oneToMany relationship and nested table

Tags: extjs

Here, the Sencha team explains how to have a one to many relationship:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

And you get more in detail here:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader

where they explain that

> "This may be a lot to take in - basically a User has many Orders, each
>   of which is composed of several OrderItems. Finally, each OrderItem
>   has a single Product."

Nice.

Now I want to have a Form where there's the user information PLUS a grid of the user's orders (not the MVC framework, just a a derived class of `form.Panel`).

How can I do this? Here's the beginning of my `form.Panel` class, where there are only fields. I just want to add to it a datagrid that is linked with `Product`.

So I create my store, like in the example, Sencha gave, then I create a grid that is linked to a `MyFramework.form.Panel`, and everything works fine. I just want to make something like a "nested table", a one to many grid in that class, to display the products that belong to the current user.

Any idea how to do this?

```
Ext.define('MyFramework.form.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.writerform',

    requires: ['Ext.form.field.Text'],

    initComponent: function(){
        this.addEvents('create');
        Ext.apply(this, {
            activeRecord: null,
            iconCls: 'icon-user',
            frame: true,
            title: 'User',
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            fieldDefaults: {
                anchor: '100%',
                width: 500,
                labelWidth: 200,
                labelAlign: 'right'
            },  
            items: [{
                xtype:'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                defaults:{
                    layout: 'fit',
                    bodyStyle:'padding:10px'
                },  
                items:[{
                    title:'General information',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Titre&nbsp;',
                        name: 'titre',
                        allowBlank: false
                    },{ 
                        fieldLabel: 'Image grande&nbsp;',
                        name: 'imgGrande'
                    }]  
                },{
                    title:'Products',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    items: [
                        /*
                         * Advices/example here!
                         * I'm stuck!
                         */
                    ]  
                }]  
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the concept of [Dynamic Form interacting with an embbed grid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/form-grid.html).

Of course that doesn't suit your needs right away. My advice, though, is to start from there and try to implement a field that will be related to an embbed grid, in your case a grid of products.

With that said, you wouldn't have a form that is filled by the embbed grid selection, but a single field that gets filled like a ComboBox, but by the grid selection.

Maybe try the [Ext.form.LookUp](https://github.com/drgomesp/extjs4-components/blob/master/src/Ext/ux/form/field/LookUp.js) field, a component that I've created that is kinda related to that problem.

This component is not exactly what you are looking for, since it works with single records, like with `one to one` relationships. But you can try to implement something from there.

Comment: I check your answer as valid, but I'll post the whole solution as an answer, so you can check what I've done.